# how to make a Layer file that can be included in HelloWorld.cpp in cocos2d-x ...?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I would like to arrange many layers in HelloWorldScene.cpp by making each layers to cpp file. But I have no idea how to start to code header files and how to include them in HelloWorld.cpp eventhough I searched around few days on Google & StakOverflow.. To explain what I want to do, I made a simple sample below. I added here only 2 Layers, but there will be over 20 layers on this 1 scene, so I want to make each of them as a file.

> > > HelloWorldScene.h

```
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    virtual bool init();

    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

    cocos2d::Layer* layer01;
    cocos2d::Layer* layer02;

    int GrossiniPops;
    cocos2d::Sprite* pMan;

    virtual void getTouched01();
    virtual void closingLayer();

};
#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

> > > HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}


bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    layer01 = Layer::create();
    this->addChild(layer01);

    layer02 = LayerColor::create(Color4B::WHITE);
    this->addChild(layer02);
    layer02->setVisible(false);

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto btn01 = cocos2d::ui::Button::create();
    btn01->loadTextures("images/moveBar.png","","");
    btn01->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(HelloWorld::getTouched01, this));
    btn01->setPosition(Point(275,250));
    layer01->addChild(btn01);

    auto btn02 = cocos2d::ui::Button::create();
    btn02->loadTextures("images/moveBar.png", "", "");
    btn02->addClickEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_0(HelloWorld::closingLayer, this));
    btn02->setPosition(Point(375, 250));
    this->addChild(btn02, 3);

    GrossiniPops = 0;
    pMan = Sprite::create("images/grossini.png");
    pMan->setPosition(Point(325, 150));
    layer01->addChild(pMan);
    pMan->setVisible(false);

    return true;
}


void HelloWorld::getTouched01()
{
    GrossiniPops++;
    if (GrossiniPops%4==2) {
        pMan->setVisible(true);
    }
    else { pMan->setVisible(false); }
}


void HelloWorld::closingLayer()
{
    log("Layer Change");

    if (layer01->isVisible()==true)
    {
        layer01->setVisible(false);
        layer02->setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        layer02->setVisible(false);
        layer01->setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the "HelloWorld.h" file in your "HelloWorld.cpp" file if you wish to use it. Put this line at the top of your "HelloWorld.cpp" file:

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"
```

That should solve it.

Here's a good reference if you'd like to read more on includes and source files in C++:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Comment: oh it was my mistake that I mistyped HelloWorldScene.cpp to HelloWorld.cpp. sorry for that. I just edited that. I already know #include "headerName.h" must be needed in cpp file, but don't know how to split  the additional layer parts. I want to handle this layer01, layer02 ... as an independent h, cpp file in order to keep this HelloWorldScene.cpp file concisely.. but have no ideas how to start this.

Comment: I guess you could create a class to handle creating a layer, then create one object for each layer that you have, possibly store them in a collection like an array for example. This way you can handle the layers as a collection of the same type, and also you'll move the layer creation code to other files (with it's own .cpp and .h file)

Comment: so in order to put different nodes and images in layer01, layer02, layer03, it may start like.. class Layer01 : public cocos2d::Layer { public: ....}, class Layer02 : public cocos2d::Layer { public: ....}, class Layer03 : public cocos2d::Layer { public: ....} in headers? and after making headers and cpps, can I use them in HelloWorldScene.cpp just by adding " auto layer01 = cocos2d::Layer01::create() ? supposing I put  #include layer01.h #include layer02.h #include layer03.h in HelloWorldScene.h

Comment: You should probably revisit a few of the fundamentals of C++. At the moment you're just throwing out ideas and mixing concepts. I could post a full example but I'm not sure it would help in your learning. It might be worth getting yourself a good C++ book to start with, there's plenty out there.

Comment: okay i see. thanks for your advice anyways. I'll try to create a layer-making class right after this comment. I have already few C/C++ books and practice all examples.. but it seems like it doesn't that helpful for me to do what I want to do. don't know exactly why is it stilll so hard even though i read through few books.. maybe it is my lack of ability...! that's why i decided to strike it one by one. I feel it helps more

Comment: Don't give up @veryBeginner! The best way is to keep trying. I'll post an example of what I mean if I find time in future.